# Centrar altura de 3 textos con HTML

Tags: html, web

Tengo una duda. Quiero centrar tres párrafos, pero que estos queden a la misma altura.

Pero en realidad me queda así:
[image: Vista Previa de HTML]

Lo que tengo de código es básico y es esto:

```
<body>
<h2 align="right">Hola</h2>
<h2 align="center"> Buenas</h2>
<h2 align="left">Buen día</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: te dejo este [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) para que aprendas a usar `flexbox`, es algo sencillo que creo que lo vas a poder implementar por vos mismo, vos podes!! cualquier cosa me avisas y te ayudo, suerte!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Saludos, que tengas buen día!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No funciona porque, para empezar, el atributo `align` no modifica el comportamiento de bloque de los elementos y, además, solo aplica a ciertas etiquetas. Revisa la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#lista_de_atributos)

Necesitas poner los títulos dentro de un contenedor y, por medio de CSS, aplicar modelo [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) o [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) para acomodarlos en una misma línea; en este ejemplo usé `flex`:

```css
h2 {
    background: #ccc;
}

.container {
    /* Mostrar en una misma línea */
    display: flex;
    /* Invertir orden, colocando el primero a la derecha */
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    /* Ocupar todo el espacio disponible y separar elementos */
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h1>Esto no funciona</h1>

<h2 align="right">Hola</h2>
<h2 align="center"> Buenas</h2>
<h2 align="left">Buen día</h2>

<h1>Esto sí funciona</h1>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Hola</h2>
    <h2>Buenas</h2>
    <h2>Buen día</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Triby Saludos!!!